# Store JSON in database

Tags: php, json

I want to store a JSON object in my SQL database; how can I do it?

```
// $app is my objet
$js = json_encode($app);
mysql_query($con, "INSERT INTO app_event (JSON_app) VALUES ('mysql_real_escape_string($js)');");
```

Comment: you don't necessarily need to do mysql_real_escape. etiherway, this seems to work fine. what exactly is the problem

Comment: I think that SQL is a bad choice for JSON. Go for MONGODB

Comment: why is it a bad idea? If his data is otherwise relational and he wants to store some stuff that he doesn't really need to query directly, it should be fine

Comment: Error that i have : mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: `mysql_query` is F-ing deprecated, stop using it... if you're still learning PHP, don't use the extensions/bits that are deprecated, because that means they'll be removed in the future. Learn the relevant parts, PDO or mysqli_*, because that are the extensions that will be around after `mysql` has finally gone to meet its maker

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with JSON. You are using a (deprecated) API by trying to guess how functions work rather than reading the docs or looking at examples.

Comment: @user2673732: The error you're getting is simply because you've mixed up the _order of the arguments_. [RTFM!](http://www.php.net/mysql_query). The signature is `resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`, so first pass the query string, then (optionally) the connection resource. Oh, and while you're reading the manual pages, _read the **red** warning box_

Comment: @user2673732 you better forget about mysql_query and other mysql only functions. Start learning theese http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
mysql_query($con,"INSERT INTO app_event (JSON_app) VALUES('mysql_real_escape_string($js)');");
```

With this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO app_event (JSON_app) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($js)."');");
```

You should consider learning more PHP, by the way.

Comment: I try it before , but doesnt work , ERROR :mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Remove $con first parameter. I've edited my post. Consider reading the PHP documentation.

Comment: @user2673732: Please, please, please: then learn to read the manual pages, and don't _waste_ your time learning about a deprecated, insecure, hopelessly outdated extension...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use php's `serialize()` to save it as text. When you will be getting this out from MySQL, you can use `unserialize()`

[php.net serialize manual](http://php.net/manual/ne/function.serialize.php)

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO app_event (JSON_app) VALUES('".serialize($app)."');");
```

Comment: Serialize a json string ? That's kinda serialinception :/

Comment: Oh, didn't notice it was a string, lol. Well why just not save the string as-is and parse it after fetching from sql

Comment: You have the same problem as the OP: the arguments to `mysql_query()` are in the wrong order.

Comment: @Alex: change the `serialize($js)` to `serialize($app)`, because `$js` is the serialized version of `$app`, which is an object

Comment: @Barmar thanks, haven't notice that, just copy - paste. Using mysql functions is a bad idea anyway, should use PDO instead

Comment: Edit it to mysqli_query